# Remove double quotes from a 'string with comma' inside csv

Tags: csv, tcl

i'm converting xls to csv. Since i'm having commas in a single column, i'm getting csv as below:

```
AMP FAN,Yes,Shichi,PON Seal,,"Brass, Silver"
AMP FAN,Yes,Shichi,PON Seal,,"Platinum, Gel"
```

If you see double quote is coming for the last column as it has comma inside. Now i'm reading this csv in **tcl** file and i'm sending to my target system. In target system this value is getting saved with double quotes (means exactly like **"Brass, Silver"**). But the user doesn't want that double quotes. So i want to set like **Brass, Silver** . is there any way i can avoid that double quotes. below is the current script i'm using.

```
while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
        #using regex to handle multiple commas in a single column

        set matches [regexp -all -inline -- {("[^\"]+"|[^,]*)(?:$|,)} $sLine]
        set lsLine {}
        foreach {a b} $matches {lappend lsLine $b}
            set sType [lindex $lsLine 0]    
            set sIsOk [lindex $lsLine 1]
            set sMaterial [lindex $lsLine 5]

            #later i'm setting sMaterial to some attribute
    }
```

Kindly help me.

Note : I will not be able to use csv package as the user don't have that in their environment and i can't add there myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove them from the token after getting each element, like this:

```
while {[gets $fileIn sLine] >= 0} {
    #using regex to handle multiple commas in a single column

    set matches [regexp -all -inline -- {("[^\"]+"|[^,]*)(?:$|,)} $sLine]
    set lsLine {}
    foreach {a b} $matches {
        # Remove the quotes here
        lappend lsLine [string map {\" {}} $b]
    }
    set sType [lindex $lsLine 0]    
    set sIsOk [lindex $lsLine 1]
    set sMaterial [lindex $lsLine 5]

    #later i'm setting sMaterial to some attribute
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much jerry :) U saved me once again :)

Comment: @Crazy2crack You're welcome! Just happened to check the new questions when saw yours, you're lucky ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
% set input  {AMP FAN,Yes,Shichi,PON Seal,,"Brass, Silver"}
AMP FAN,Yes,Shichi,PON Seal,,"Brass, Silver"
%  regsub -all \" $input {}
AMP FAN,Yes,Shichi,PON Seal,,Brass, Silver
%
```